# Jsoup doc.title

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I want to parse document by Jsoup and get title of document. Then set text in Textview to this title.

Here's my code who not work. When I'm turning on this activity I have 'ogloszenia' text not Google title.

```
package pl.xxxxx.xxxxx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Document doc;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();
            String sd = doc.title();
            TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tekst);
            textview.setText(sd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Fragment of activity_main2

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="ogłoszenia"
    android:id="@+id/tekst"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: add details about the issues you are facing

Comment: The text after turning on this activity is 'ogloszenia' not Google title

Comment: When I run this code I get 'google'. Try to set your user agent string to match your browser. You can also print the `doc` to the logcat or to a file and see what you get.

Comment: yeah , i am also getting the same output as `Google`

Comment: After set user agent to chrome still not work